# Find the eigenvalues from the eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I don't understand this question
how to solve it?

If the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ are $\lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = 4.79, \lambda_3 
= 0.21 $

a) Find the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$.
b) Find the eigenvalues of $A^2$.
c) Find the eigenvalues of $5A$.

Comment: You may take $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,4.79,0.21)$. Then  it's easy to compute (assuming it is a $3\times 3$-matrix).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Assuming it's $3\times3$.

Comment: Think about the geometrical significance of the eigenvalues.

Comment: A better approach than simply reciting a problem and saying "I don't understand" is to share what you *do* understand about the problem. Your interest in the problem suggests that you have some understanding of it, so help Readers by giving us a starting point to begin with your study.

Comment: To build on @hardmath’s comment, see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) for ways to improve this one.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Start with the fundamental eigenvector equation $Ax=\lambda x$. What do you get if you multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$? by $A$? by $5$?

Answer (score 0):

Hints (require some self work):

(1)See what happens when $A$ is diagonal.

(2) If $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A=PDP^{-1}$ when $D$ is diagonal.